# Instagram API 500 Internal Server Error (not fixed? bad code?)

Tags: instagram

I [saw](http://developers.instagram.com/post/82701625883/api-returning-500-errors-on-specific-ip) that folks were having trouble with 500 Internal Server errors when using the Instagram API about a month ago, but I'm still getting it and other posts here say those issues were fixed. Here's the Python code I'm using to get historical, location-specific data from Instagram - am I doing something wrong?

```
import urllib2
import time

outFileName = "instagramData.txt"
out = open(outFileName, "wb")

startTime = 1379249920

while startTime <= 1381841920:
    for i in range(0,4500):
        urlStr = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=SOMELAT&lng=SOMELONG&distance=4000&min_timestamp=" + `startTime` + "&max_timestamp=" + `startTime + 5` + "&access_token=****"
        print urlStr
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(urlStr)
            html = response.read()
        except Exception:
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
        out.write(html)
        startTime += 5
        time.sleep(.8)
```